# How to resume training of a model?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have not GPU support so it often happens that my model takes hours to train. Can I train my model in batches , for example if I want to have 100 epochs for my model,but due to power cut my training stops(at 50th epoch) but when I retrain my model I want to train it from where it was left (from 50th epoch).

It would be much appreciated if anyone can explain it by some example.

Comment: This is possible with most (all?) mainstream deep learning frameworks by simply storing the model every N training iterations and checking for the last stored model before starting the training. Which framework are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow

Comment: @ncasas could you please give how to do the same using keras ?

Comment: A [simple google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=keras+resume+training) leads you to the appropriate information.

Answer (score 3):

With tensorflow, currently the most straightforward and easy way to get persistence for your model is to use a [`tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredTrainingSession). You just need to use it instead the normal `tf.Session()` that is frequently used. This an illustrative Python snippet:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(checkpoint_dir='/tmp/mymodel',
                                       save_summaries_secs=600) as sess:
   _ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={...})
```

With this, your model is automagically saved every 600 secs in `/tmp/mymodel` and restored the next time you restart the program.